# How to scroll an accessibilitynodeinfo?

Tags: android, scroll, accessibilityservice

I am building an accessiblity service for 3-party application using AccessibilityService API. But I don't know how to scroll an accessibilitynodeinfo backward? Can you guys help me out? 
node.perform(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_SCROLL_BACKSCROLL) didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want:

```
void scrollBackward(AccessibilityNodeInfo) throws NotScrollable {

    while (node != null) {

        if (node.isScrollable()) {
            node.performAction(ACTION_SCROLL_BACKWARD);
            return;
        }

        node = node.getParent();

    }

    throw new NotScrollable("This node cannot be scrolled");
}
```

Note: I'm on my phone typing this up, so forgive me if this doesn't quite compile.  It should be very close.